# HTML Body shows cz-shortcut-listen="true" with Chrome's Developer Tools?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was testing some HTML code I'm making, and while using the Developer Tools on Google Chrome version 22.0.1229.94 m, I saw the `<body>` tag has the attribute `cz-shortcut-listen="true"` (which of course is not on my code). **What does it mean and why is it showing up?** (I tried looking it up in google, but found nothing relevant)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 397, accepted):

It's being added by the Colorzilla browser extension.

https://twitter.com/brianpemberton/status/201455628143689728

*The Twitter link no longer works, but with the help of archive.org the content was retrieved:*

> Brian Pemberton @brianpemberton
>
> cz-shortcut-listen is inserted into html by the colorzilla extension/add-on. fyi for confused web developers seeing it when inspecting pages
>
> 4:35 PM - 12 May 2012

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a standard prefix for extension injections like `browser-extension-` / `b-ext-` or something. That way, it'd be a lot easier to figure out what's random cruft and what was put there by the page author. I know you can just run a different Chrome user profile that has no extensions installed, but sometimes those very extensions - Colorzilla, even - are really useful for analysing web pages.

Comment: Write a suggestion to leading browser vendors - that's a good idea

Comment: @twome @martin `cz-` in `cz-shortcut-listen` is there for `ColorZilla` already. Yeah, however browsers should also take that as a standard protocol for all extensions out there :)

Comment: Feels like a data-dash attribute would've been a better choice

Comment: why?... @Stimul8d

Comment: I thought it was some kind of *Czech language* compatibility plugin.

Comment: Funny how 8 years later, it still confuses people (probably testing their own code) and will  likely continue to do so for many more years.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP Funny how 11 years later, it still confuses people (probably testing their own code) and will likely continue to do so for many more years. The link to Twiiter no longer works, and searching for "cz-shortcut-listen" only shows other people wondering what it is.