# How does browser converts HTML string received from server in react server side rendering into HTML DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-ssr

I have started learning React Server Side Rendering. Then I configured "**index.js**" file as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const React  = require('react');
const renderToString = require('react-dom/server').renderToString;
const Home = require('./client/components/home').default;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const content = renderToString(<Home></Home>);
    res.send(content); // Statement1
});

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log("App listening to port 3000");
});
```

So, at Statement1 in above code, we are returning string form "Home" component (because "renderToString" converts HTML into string.

When I inspect DOM, I get following code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
<div data-reactroot="">I'm home component</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, my question is that how browser is converting HTML string (received as response from server) into DOM elements, and how this "`<body>`" tag is being added?

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is a `cz-shortcut-listen` attribute on the body start tag, I would assume that it is getting added by the `renderToString` and not the browser.

It is something of a leap to get to that conclusion by looking at the top level of the server-side code and the DOM inspector without looking at the generated HTML source at all.

(After doing some further reading, it seems that attribute is added by [a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147210/html-body-shows-cz-shortcut-listen-true-with-chromes-developer-tools) you have installed. My point about actually looking at the HTML source stands though).

Browsers will follow the [the specification for parsing HTML documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing) which includes provisions for handling elements with [tag omission rules](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-tag-omission) like the [body element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element).

It will start out in [The "before html" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode), find a div start tag and hit:

> Create an html element whose node document is the Document object. Append it to the Document object. Put this element in the stack of open elements.
>
> Switch the insertion mode to "before head", then reprocess the token.

And then that will trigger the creation of the head element and so on.

Comment: Thanks for answering. "cz-shortcut-listen" is added by "colorzilla" chrome extension. But I don't think you answer is sufficient for my question, "How browser is converting received HTML string into DOM nodes?". Please look into this question once.

Comment: @sinha.kushagra — This does cover it. Please read beyond the first paragraph. If you do, you'll see I already mentioned colorzila.